# Python mechanize login into website no form found

Tags: python-2.7, mechanize

I'm trying to log into the shipping portals i need to scrape some details off one of the inner pages. I've using the script below.

```
import mechanize
username = 'namehere'   # your username/email
password = 'password here'   # your password

br = mechanize.Browser()


# browser settings (used to emulate a browser)
br.set_handle_equiv(True)
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.set_handle_referer(True)
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_debug_http(False)
br.set_debug_responses(False)
br.set_debug_redirects(False)
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

br.open('http://tracking.parcelforce.net') # open parcelforce

#List the forms
#for form in br.forms():
#print "Form name:", form.name
#print form

br.select_form(name="SNP_SCM_login")
br.form[ "LOGIN_FORM" ] = username
br.form[ "PASSWORD_FORM" ] = password


br.submit() # submit the login data
print(br.response().read()) # print the response
```

the output i'm getting back is no form found. If anyone can assist would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've re-looked at this and to solve the problem i've used a PHP Script to use CURL and use login data from the cached session to get passed the login screen.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is, the page you hit is populated just by JS, and there's no objects created for you to pick up.  Mechanize needs an object to reach the form, but no forms are found on the br.open()

You can check it out yourself:

```
request = br.open('http://tracking.parcelforce.net') # open parcelforce
print request.read()
```

And you already have this which returns you no form:

```
for form in br.forms():
  print "Form name:", form.name
  print form
```

And I've tried selecting the form by:

```
br.select_form(nr=0)
```

which is supposed to select the first form, but no form is found.  Your best bet is to not go with mechanize unfortunately.

Try Watir (Ruby) or simply go Selenium and use scrapping through there.